# Getting an error trying to input a constant datetime using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, datetime, pyspark, null

```
df = df.withColumn('Arrive_time', lit(np.datetime64('NaT')))
```

I am getting the error

"numpy.datetime64 object has no attribute '_get_object_id'"

What is the right way to input a null datetime into a pyspark dataframe?

Comment: You can do `to_timestamp(F.lit(None))` but out of curiosity, what is the use case of null datetime in a column?  How do you plan to use this column?

Comment: I have to combine this with another dataframe that has existing datetimes

Comment: You can possibly combine without adding a column.  ex: `df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True)` or could be with `join`.   Do you want to expand this question by what you are actually trying to do?